# Not able to DEBUG on JBoss

Tags: java, jboss

I have an application in which upon hitting a URL, I need debugging to do.
After a long struggle(but only for once) I was able to get it to debug. But as soon I again tried it for second time the local server is giving me following logs!!
Can anyone tell me that what went wrong the second time? And how can I fix it?

EDIT: I am using Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 6.4.0.GA

```
14:36:28,583 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) Failed to define class com.mmm.common.util.io.MmmURLStreamHandlerFactory$MyHttpHandler in Module "deployment.snaps-ear-prod-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.snaps-web-prod-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/mmm/common/util/io/MmmURLStreamHandlerFactory$MyHttpHandler (Module "deployment.snaps-ear-prod-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.snaps-web-prod-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.mmm.snaps.service.IoTimeoutService.initialize(IoTimeoutService.java:54) [snaps-java-common-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
        at com.mmm.snaps.service.init.InitializationService.doInitializeServices(InitializationService.java:200) [snaps-java-common-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
        at com.mmm.snaps.service.init.InitializationService.initializeServicesIfNeeded(InitializationService.java:105) [snaps-java-common-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
        at com.mmm.snaps.filter.AbstractSnapsRequestFilter.performPreProcessing(AbstractSnapsRequestFilter.java:354) [snaps-java-common-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
        at com.mmm.snaps.filter.AbstractSnapsRequestFilter.performPreProcessing(AbstractSnapsRequestFilter.java:290) [snaps-java-common-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
        at com.mmm.snaps.servlet.SnapsServlet.handleRequest(SnapsServlet.java:98) [snaps-java-common-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
        at com.mmm.snaps.servlet.SnapsServlet.doGet(SnapsServlet.java:200) [snaps-java-common-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/net/www/protocol/http/Handler
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler from [Module "deployment.snaps-ear-prod-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.snaps-web-prod-3.13.1.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        ... 34 more
```

Comment: You might want to tell us which version of JBoss you're refering to.

Comment: I guess `com.mmm.snaps.service.IoTimeoutService` etc. is your code, right? In that case it seems as if you're using `sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler` directly. Please note that this might break eventually since the `sun.*` etc. packages might not be visible to all classloaders or might even be removed eventually. I'd assume you're working with different Java versions, don't you?

Comment: try to add a dependency to sun.jdk in your module.xml or jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: Thanksss....adding dependency in my standalone.xml made it worked !!!!